# Timed push message's | ionic | angularjs | cordova |

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I'm making a timed push notification to remind customers of their service date. (2 years from their purchase date)

Now i had this working with local notifications but found out it would not be stored the time needed
(2 years is long)

```
         cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: 10,
            title: "bla",
            text: "Bel ons nu voor een onderhoudsbeurt!",
            at: $scope.data.notify,
            icon: "http://bla.nl/icon.png",
            data: { meetingId:"red" }
          });
```

So now **i'm wondering how to setup the cordova push plugin to send the message at the correct time** the same way i did with local notifications (no clear explanation in the docs(couldn't find it in other plugin docs too))

Im totally stuck i tried telerik and pushwoosh already but 50 dollars a month is too much for this service they are offering.

**I'm sorry I cant offer anymore information. google keeps giving me nothing on this subject so don't have any real starting point except for the local push**

Comment: To use push notifications like that you will need some sort of server that can store the dates that notifications need to be sent and can run a batch job each day, looking for dates that have been reached and send the push notifications. Alternatively, if the user will be using your app regularly you can check the date each time the app runs and if it is within, say, 30 days of the service date then schedule a local notification

Comment: is there any tutorial or something for me to learn how to do it?  i'm really interested in learning this

Comment: I don't know much about Cordova but in a native ObjC/Swift app it is pretty trivial; simply check the date each time the app launches and if it is 30 days or less than service date and no local notification is already scheduled then schedule a local notification for the service  date.

Comment: Problem is they possibly not going to check every month, the only function is giving info and remind them for the checkup... so ya ... (not makes a lot of sense but my boss told me to do it)

Comment: Then you will need some sort of server approach. I would have suggest parse.com but they are going away in a year. Backendless.com looks ok but I haven't used them yet

Comment: Thanks this should do the trick! `Synchronous Publish:
var channel = "TestChannel",
   message = "Hello, world!",
   pubOps = null,
   deliveryOps = new DeliveryOptions({
       publishAt: (new Date()).getTime() + 60 * 1000 // 1 minute delay
   });
var response = Backendless.Messaging.publish( channel, message, pubOps, deliveryOps );
// message has been published, message status is available via response.status
// if publish failed - error is described in response.errorMessage`